# Schema factory returns IllegalArgumentException when using W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI

Tags: java, android, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate an XML against an XSD in Java (for an Android App).

I get the following error when trying to create a new Schema istance:

```
SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(SchemaFactory.java:192)
```

Why do I get that?